# How to open a bootstrap-select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-select in a form with many entries.
Now i would like to validate the form in a way that the user is guided more precisely through the missing fields.
so i use:

```
$('html, body').animate
```

to scroll to the missing field / select item
and then:

```
field.focus();
```

to set the cursor into an input field

Now for the select items i would like to open the dropdown in that case.

Is there a way to do that?

i was trying the following thanks to tip from muggles:

```
function goToFormField(field){
    var offset=80;
    $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: field.parent().offset().top - offset
    }, 100,"easeInOutCirc",function(){
        if(field.is("input")){
            field.focus();
        }else if(field.is("select")){
            field.selectpicker('show')          
        }
    }
    );
}
```

but it did not work.
EDIT: the mentioned function selectpicker('show') just shows the select-item, not the dropdown contents.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Found a simple solution [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/484):

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('toggle')
```

Basically it toggles the `open/close` state. Therefore no `refresh` required.

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap-select only requires an open class to be added in the same class as select element, for example:

```
// To Open
$('.selectpicker').addClass('open');

// To Close
$('.selectpicker').removeClass('open');
```

Comment: You should also note that you have to call refresh method like $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')

Comment: @GezaTuri only if you want to reload the data, otherwise it worked in my case without calling refresh.

Comment: I found `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('toggle')` in [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/484), which actually toggles the open/close state. Thus no `refresh` required.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about [this](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin for Bootstrap.

If so, according to the [documentation](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#3), the plugin has a .show() method which programmatically shows the bootstrap select menu.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('show');
```

Comment: yes, i do use this plugin.
however i cannot get the mentinoed function to work.

here is my code:
`function goToFormField(field){
  
  
  var offset=80;
  
  $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: field.parent().offset().top - offset
  }, 100,"easeInOutCirc",function(){
   if(field.is("input")){
    field.focus();
   }else if(field.is("select")){
    field.selectpicker('show')   
   }
  }
  );
 }`

Comment: @zantafio can you create a https://jsfiddle.net.net/ also I would recommend editing your original question with that code as the formatting would be a lot more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```
setTimeout(function(){
       $('#selector_id').next().click();
   }, 500);
```

It will click the toggle dropdown button and will make the dropdown-menu open.
Just replace "selector_id" with your required id.